# Searching in a subtree in orgmode without narrowing

Tags: org-mode, search, region, isearch

Is there a way to search in org mode in emacs in a certain subtree without narrowing or "narrowing" and "widening" the way to go?

Comment: Why do you believe there is any need to narrow when searching in `org-mode`?  How about using:  `org-search-view`, `org-tags-view` and `org-agenda-list`?  See also the manual describing advanced searching techniques:  https://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/advanced-searching.html

Comment: but i want to search in a special tree @lawlist

Comment: @David - Would you provide an example please? I'm not sure what you're searching for or the reason for the search. There might be a really easy way to do exactly what you want but I need some additional information.

Comment: I have different trees in org mode like *test *notes. And under each note there is some writing, but i want to just search in the writing under *test, but not from *notes

Answer (score 1):

Can you easily select a tree that you want to search? I don't use Org, but I imagine there are commands to do that kind of thing: select specific subtrees etc.

If you use [Isearch+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IsearchPlus) (code: [`isearch+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/isearch%2b.el)) then you can [limit isearch to within the active *region*](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IsearchPlus#isearchp-restrict-to-region-flag) - you need not *narrow* to the region.

That lets you continue to see the surrounding context. (You can optionally dim it a bit, to concentrate on the text you're searching.)

You can also limit isearch to a *multi*-region, that is, to a *set of **zones*** (which are easy to define, either interactively or programmatically) or its *complement*. For this, you also need library [Zones](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Zones) or library [`isearch-prop.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/isearch-prop.el).